# Not able to put a break point for a function being run in Background C#, Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2012, backgroundworker

I am not able to put a break point in a function being run as a background thread.Is it possible to debug a background thread.

following is the implementation :

```
// Thread settings

SettingTestThread1();

BackgroundWorker testThread1 ;
private void SettingTestThread1()
{

  testThread1 = new BackgroundWorker();


  testThread1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(testThread1Handler);
  testThread1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(testThread1CompletedHandler);
  thread.Sleep(50) ; testThread1 .WorkerReportsProgress = true;


}


  private void testThread1Handler(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
             //body of the testThread
             func1();
             func2();
             func3();


        }

 private void testThread1CompletedHandler(object sensor, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
             //Clean up , destruct-or calling, disposing off variable
        }

main()
{

   SettingTestThread1();
   testThread1.RunWorkerAsync();


}
```

But when I run this I am not able to see the break point hitting any of the func1,2 or 3 bodies.
I am calling SettingTestThread1() in the main before testThread1.RunWorkerAsync also in the code.

Rgds,
Rp

Comment: It might help if you threw it - [`RunWorkerAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h01xszh2.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what happens here is your program exists before background thread is called.
Try add a sleep AFTER having run the background worker:

```
public static void main()
{

    SettingTestThread1();
    testThread1.RunWorkerAsync();

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Indeed, Terminaison of background threads is not mandatory for a program to exit. If you want your main thread to wait for the Background thread to be over... well, don't use background threads, but normal threads.